# JQuery Ajax web method link to test domain not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a webmethod in my solution which is called using Jquery Ajax method. This works great in my development solution. BUt does not work when uploading to my test domain
When I upload the solution to the test domain:

```
wwww."".com/test/
```

It can't seem to access my method. I looked into the problem using firebug and it looks like its looking for:

```
    www."".com/webservices/service
```

Because I am using the test environment it should change to find the webservices folder, like so:

```
www."".com/test/webservices/service
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function GetData() {     

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../WebServices/Service.asmx/GetData",
        data: JSON.stringify({

        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        { alert(ajaxOptions); }
    });
   }  

   </script>
```

my c# is:

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public string GetData()
    {

    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can solve this problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebServices/Service.asmx/GetData") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove one of the `../`:

```
url: "../WebServices/Service.asmx/GetData",
```